# VIM: search file for NON-matching numerics

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

Looking for some vim help with searching a file

I'd like assistance to find some data in a file that has, say, 1.6 million records/lines.

The records follow a pattern very similar to what is below, and I would like to find all records WITHOUT 16 digits in the second column of numbers and then have all these records/lines brought to the top or taken to the bottom.

For this example, I've made some of the records NOT have 16 digits. There are only three records with 16 digits and they should be taken to the bottom and the five without 16 digits should be taken to the top.
[updated the data example but it does not align properly here...see: http://pastiebin.com/53059f6a0a218

```
A1553419V 4111111851111111 111811_2519104                                       
U1753419V 411001111111111  111811_2519104                                       
I1053419V 41111111881111   111811_2519104                                       
J1253419V 3566002020360505 111811_2519104                                       
P1153419V 378282246310005  111811_2519104                                       
C1953419V 12345678900000   111811_2519104                                       
T1953419V 852741369123     111811_2519104                                       
W1353419V 5610591081018250 111812_2519104
```

The lines end on column 80, by the way.

So in this example, I would want to know about lines: 2, 3, 5, 6, 7.
Lines 1,5,8 all have 16 digit numbers in the center column.

This really basic syntax would simply highlight all 16 digit numbers but going through a million plus records for that is silly: `/\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d`

Thanks for any assistance with a resolution to this.

Yes, any scripting language would (probably) be a better fit, and if you're willing to write something simple up to help out the world, be my guest.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
:v/ [0-9]\{16} /m 0
```

- `:v` - for lines not matching
- `/ [0-9]\{16} /` - space, 16 digits, space
- `m 0` - move them to top (use `$` instead of `0` to move to bottom)

EDIT: As Ingo commented, `{` needs to be escaped for this to work.

Comment: My results can be read here: http://pastiebin.com/530592598c418

Any suggestions?

Comment: `[0-9]` can be written as `\d`, and you either need to switch to very magic mode with `\v` or use `\{16}`.

Comment: This may or may not matter, but @danadam's solution reverses the order of all lines moved to the top.  Change `m0` to `m$` and they will be moved to the bottom of the file, instead of the top, and the order will be preserved.

Comment: Thank you danadam for your assistance, this is now working!

Ingo, thank you for editing my post and assisting danadam.